# How To fix E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile

I make application for android app. My application is running perfectly in another phone device, but in s*msung my app always Error :

> E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file

How can I fix this? thanks in advance

Comment: Any fix here ? Randomly happens to my app. any fix ?

Comment: To fix this issue, try using Image Loading libraries such as Coil, Glide, or Picasso. Hope this help.